# Making transactions and don't waiting for response

Tags: web3js

Is there a way to submit a transaction and don't wait for it to be confirmed or rejected? Because now when I run my nodejs script it does not stop to run until the transaction is confirmed or rejected. I am using function:

```
      async () => { 
   await web3.unlockAccount();
   await contract = web3.eth.Contract(Abi,Address);
    contract.methods.method(params).send({from: address});
    }
```

In theory it should not wait until the transaction is confirmed, but it does.

Comment: It doesn't wait, the Contract methods by web3 return a promise, so they are asynchronous by default, how can this be ?

Comment: I don't know, but when I submit transaction the script just freezes until the transaction is confirmed or rejected (I.E. The script is still running while transaction is pending). I want to just submit the transaction and quit the script.

Comment: try something without the async. then try adding `then`and `catch` of the returned promise to see the results in clear.

Comment: But I need async for other things in my script

Comment: Node will not stop a program until all pending task are processed. If you are on Linux or other unix like OS you can send it to background.

Answer (score 0):

```
 contract.methods.method(params).send({from: address})

 .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
                console.log(hash);
            })
    .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){
        //
    })
    .on('receipt', function(receipt){
     console.log(receipt);
    })
```

This should not wait for hash / receipt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I use this:

```
 contract.methods
 .method(params)
 .send({from: address})
 .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
     console.log(hash);
     // Store tx hash, so you can use that to check if tx failed or succedded
     res.json(hash); // send or return hash
 })
```

Txn hash is generated quickly so it is returned instantly which you can use to process further and it won't wait for tx to be confirmed.

Hope it helps!